# location of JQuery error validation

Tags: jquery, css

I know that we can use errorPlacement to set where we want the error message will be. I have created a css that would help this. Here is the code:

```
label.error {
    display: inline;
    clear: both;
    color:#200;
    margin:5px 0;
}
```

what is it that I must do to display the error next to the `<input>` using the error label
  that I have created

Answer (score 1):

Check out the errorPlacement: option here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate

```
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {

     if (element.attr("name") == "someName"){
       error.insertBefore("input[name=someName]:first");
     }
     else{
       error.insertAfter(element);
     }
    },
```

Another example from the api I linked above

```
    $("#myform").validate({
      errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
         error.appendTo( element.parent("td").next("td") );
       },
       debug:true
     })
```

**edit**

It looks like in the example, they are just styling the `.warning` label to be displayed inline.

```
    #stepForm label.warning {
        text-align: left;
        width: auto;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 0 0 10px;
        float: none;
        clear: none;
        display: inline;
        color: #CC3366;
        font-size: 10px;
        border: none;
        border-top: 1px dotted #CC3366;
    }
```

Comment: I just changed my question at the same time you answered

Comment: Ah, I see. Can you post some of the code surrounding your input. For instance is the input inside a `<li>` or `<div>`? And is that outer container have a set width?